# Показать/скрыть элементы многоуровневого списока

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется многоуровневый список. Элементы списка строятся по принципу папок и файлов. Изначально видны только корневые папки. Задача в том, чтобы при клике на папку, она раскрывалась. При повторном - сворачивалась сама, сворачивая все внутренние папки которые были раскрыты. Использование toggle приводит к тому, что при повторном раскрытии корневой папки, ранее открытые внутреннее папки остаются.
Подскажите пожалуйста какое-нибудь решение.

Comment: Покажите пример кода, где у вас проблема!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, можно при клике добавлять класс `open` к вложенным меню. А при повторном всем удалять.

```js
$('.list li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var subList = $(this).children('.sub-list');
  
  if (subList.hasClass('open')) {
    $(this).find('.sub-list').removeClass('open');
  } else {
    subList.addClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.sub-list {
  display: none;
}

.sub-list.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>item 1
    <ul class="sub-list">
      <li>item 1.1
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li>item 1.1.1
            <ul class="sub-list">
              <li>item 1.1.1.1</li>
              <li>item 1.1.1.2</li>
              <li>item 1.1.1.3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>item 1.1.2</li>
          <li>item 1.1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>item 1.2
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li>item 1.1.1</li>
          <li>item 1.1.2</li>
          <li>item 1.1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>item 1.3
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li>item 1.1.1</li>
          <li>item 1.1.2</li>
          <li>item 1.1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item 2
    <ul class="sub-list">
      <li>item 1.1
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li>item 1.1.1</li>
          <li>item 1.1.2</li>
          <li>item 1.1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>item 1.2
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li>item 1.1.1</li>
          <li>item 1.1.2</li>
          <li>item 1.1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>item 1.3
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li>item 1.1.1</li>
          <li>item 1.1.2</li>
          <li>item 1.1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item 3
    <ul class="sub-list">
      <li>item 1.1
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li>item 1.1.1</li>
          <li>item 1.1.2</li>
          <li>item 1.1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>item 1.2
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li>item 1.1.1</li>
          <li>item 1.1.2</li>
          <li>item 1.1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>item 1.3
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li>item 1.1.1</li>
          <li>item 1.1.2</li>
          <li>item 1.1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```